# digital countdown animation with flipped numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create my own digital countdown like [**this**](http://flipclockjs.com/)

I downloaded the source code, but can't understand which part is responsible for this markup and animation.

Could anyone help to complete my try?

There is no need to write code for entire countdown, just for a single part which is animated, for example for seconds.

Thanks.

```js
var dt = "2019:01:01 00:00:00";
var parts = dt.split(/[- :]/);
parts[1]--;
const targ = new Date(...parts);

function givemediff() {
 var diff = Date.parse(targ) - Date.parse(new Date());
 var sec = Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60);
 var minutes = Math.floor((diff / 1000 / 60) % 60);
 var hours = Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
 var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
 return {'diff': diff, 'days': days, 'hours': hours, 'minutes': minutes, 'sec': sec};
}
function updateClock() {
 var t = givemediff();
 $('#clockday').text(('0' + t.days).slice(-2));
 $('#clockhour').text(('0' + t.hours).slice(-2));
 $('#clockmin').text(('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2));
 
 if (t.sec < 10) {var tsec = '0' + t.sec;}
 else {var tsec = t.sec;}
 $('#clockpartsec').toggleClass('xflipped'); 
 $('#clockinsec').text(tsec); 
 
 if (t.diff <= 0) {
  clearInterval(timeinterval);
 }
}

updateClock();
var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

```css
.clockwrap{
    display: inline-block;
 white-space:nowrap;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
}

.clockpart{
 display:inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 padding:5px 9px;
 border-right:2px solid white;
 .perspective: 200px;
 position: relative;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-origin: center center;
 transition: transform 1s;
 .background:lightseagreen;
}

.clockpartins{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 .overflow:hidden;
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.xflipped{
 transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='clockwrap' id='clockwrap'>

<div class='clockpart'>
<div class='clockpartins' id='clockday'></div>
</div>

<div class='clockpart'>
<div class='clockpartins' id='clockhour'></div>
</div>

<div class='clockpart'>
<div class='clockpartins' id='clockmin'></div>
</div>

<div class='clockpart' id='clockpartsec'>
<div class='clockpartins' id='clockinsec'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you need?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO, I need the final result as on provided link on top of my post

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.